# RVM not detected in multi-user installation

Tags: permissions, cgroups, rvm

I have two ubuntu users `deploy` and `developers` I install rvm using Multi-User:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

by default this one will create rvm group. The rvm will be installed in `/usr/local/rvm`

then I add these two users users to rvm

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm deploy
$ sudo usermod -a -G rvm developers
```

I also put this in **.bash_profile**

```
[[ -s /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

when I logout and login again to one of the users I trigger this

```
$ rvm list

# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.
```

Why is it that the rvm is not being detected?